# Cross tires that work on street and trail

Tags: tire, cyclocross

I recently when on the trail with my cross bike it has Vittoria Zaffiro 32 tires, didn't take long to washout. Is there a tire out there that will work equally well on the dirt and the street since I use this bike to commute but trails are close.

Comment: Everything in life is a compromise - that's why there are so many different options available.  If there was one tyre that did everything well, it would be the only tyre people used.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that Zaffiro tires would be suitable for cyclocross.

Comment: There are other ways to solve the problem. One is to learn to ride what you have, in whatever conditions you face (within reason, since you don't explain what level of trails you're tackling). This approach pushes you to extend your skills, which could save your life one day. If the trails are more extreme, then a second wheelset can be a good way to go, with different tires on each (and even different builds to handle the different conditions).

Comment: Anything that works in dirt is less safe when cornering on a wet road than a smooth road tire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, i can't recommend one because that is not what the site is for.. However look for one with micro knobby center and more aggressive shoulder knobs. Something that when going straight on pavement will offer low rolling resistance but has plenty of bite in the corners. Many brands make them.

One other approach would be to decide which is more important or more frequent for you and lean more towards that style of tire. For example if you are more concerned with riding trails and not so much with the extra effort they will require on pavement then go for something knobby but densely spaced such as something like this:
[image]
or this
[image]

Or if you are more concerned with smooth rolling on concrete but want a little bite on the random occasion go for something more like this with a smoother center.

[image]
or this
[image]

Comment: The first two look better for the job, IMO.

Comment: @andy256 The second two will have a Jeckyll-and-Hyde personality on wet pavement when going into a turn. Their central tread is like a road tire, but as soon as you tilt, you're riding on squirmy knobs.

Comment: @Kaz Yes, I agree!

Comment: They would be my choice as well, or a small block 8, but i figured i'd provide some options.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You need to realize that choosing cycling equipment is a matter of dealing with trade offs.  A tire designed to be the "best" on trail will generally be less efficient rolling on pavement, and a tire designed to roll with maximal efficiency on pavement will generally handle poorly on trail.

What you need to decide is where you want to excel and choose a tire suited for that, or decide that you want a tire that works "ok" on both and be comfortable with that decision.  My guess is that you you will probably be best suited choosing a tire more suited to trail, and less so to street.  The tire will roll less well than a set of slicks on pavement, but while you are exerting a few extra watts on your commute, you can be comfortable in the knowledge that your tires are ready to take whatever trails you may soon try.

Comment: You might think so, but that http://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/ website has some surprising results. There are some 2.2+ inch wide tires featuring knobby tread with better rolling resistance results than some 35mm road tires. The tread or lack thereof isn't everything.

Comment: Yes, there are many other considerations in tire performance than tread.  However, in general, there are so many riding conditions to consider, no tire is best.  Even the "best" road racing tire, will generally be so light that it will be inappropriate for training.  My point is that choosing tires for more than one set of riding conditions is always a compromise.